# Facebook Account Kit require an appsecret_proof argument Error

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to retrieve the user PhoneNumber/email using Facebook Account kit.

I'm always getting an error as response:

> 200: Server generated an error: 145: API calls from the server require
>   an appsecret_proof argument

I already Disabled the option on Facebook Developer Dash Board.

> Require app secret for server API calls

Here is my code:

```
public void onLoginPhone(final View view) {
  final Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AccountKitActivity.class);
  AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder =
    new AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder(
      LoginType.PHONE,
      AccountKitActivity.ResponseType.CODE); // or .ResponseType.TOKEN
  // ... perform additional configuration ...
  intent.putExtra(
    AccountKitActivity.ACCOUNT_KIT_ACTIVITY_CONFIGURATION,
    configurationBuilder.build());
  startActivityForResult(intent, APP_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

and this is onActivityResult:

```
AccountKit.getCurrentAccount(new AccountKitCallback<Account>() {
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(final Account account) {
    // Get Account Kit ID
    String accountKitId = account.getId();

    // Get phone number
    PhoneNumber phoneNumber = account.getPhoneNumber();
    String phoneNumberString = phoneNumber.toString();

    // Get email
    String email = account.getEmail();
  }

  @Override
  public void onError(final AccountKitError error) {
    // Handle Error
  }
});
```

Comment: That specific API call requires appsecret_proof and has to be done from the server. What you Disabled is just to not require it for all API calls.

Answer (score 12):

Simple solution to solve above problem, just follow following step.

**Step 1 :** Go to Facebook developer console

```
     https://developers.facebook.com/
```

**Step 2 :** Select your application from the

```
     https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
```

**Step 3:** After selecting your application Click on **Account kit** located at left side panel of console below the **product** Title.

**Step 4 :** After click on Account kit you see the **Reuired App Secret** switch button with yes/no option right side of it.

**Step 5 :** ***Turn Off (No) the Reuired App Secret*** from the there ( below the allow sms login )

**Step 6 :** Click on **Save changes** tab.

**Step 7 :** Run your application, you will got whatever you want.

If you have still any query ask me to any time. may be these help to you or other person.

Comment: This did not work for me, as I am facing the same problem and the require app secret is turned off in my app, do you suggest another solution? thanks

Comment: I have the settings turned on exactly as recommended and STILL get this error, but only on LTE, not on Wifi. https://imgur.com/a/DQZLa

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. The three steps which solved my problem:

1. Turn off the option "App Require Secret"
2. Make sure the option "Enable Client Access Token Flow " has turned on, set 
   to "YES"
3. User this `AccountKitActivity.ResponseType.TOKEN instead of AccountKitActivity.ResponseType.CODE`

ResponseType.CODE will never return you the mobile number.

Hope it helps.